# 2 merge modules have same file name in wix

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wix3.6

I have several existing merge modules and one created by me. Lets call my module as 'A'. My merge modules and one existing merge module(say B) contains a file with the same name(customUI.resources) but with different content.

I am making an installer which uses both modules A & B. I want to use the customUI.resources file from module 'A'. When i compile the installer.wix file, it gives me the error as:

> light.exe : error LGHT0204 : ICE30: The target file 'va2q4hvb.res|CustomUI.resources' is installed in '[ProgramFilesFolder]\abc\' by two different components on an LFN system: '_5AD14D2401C1408A8B1117B8B85F53E3.7C263653_7A00_4D9C_B52A_39AF1892BC49' and 'Adapter_Config_ja.BABCE01A_0CB9_4A62_B877_5E520A53D609'.

This breaks component reference counting. How can i resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Are you in control of authoring module a and b?

If so, author the files as 2 different filenames and use the CopyFile element ( DuplicateFile table ) to duplicate the specific name to the common desired name.  Also put mutually exclusive conditions on the components to make sure only one or the other gets installed.

Then in your main installer set a property to decide which one gets installed.  The result will pass all ICE validation tests and give you the desired behavior.

Comment: I can control only module a. The other module is made by someone else. I want to overwrite the file which is present in module b. When I compile both modules in a installer, it gives me the above error.

Comment: So you never want to file from moduble b to be installed?  You could create a process that updates module B during the (pre)build to remove the offending file from the module.  This would result in an MSI that only has the file from module a.

Comment: This illustrates one of the things to consider when making merge modules.  They are *atomic*, *sealed* encapsulations of components.  When variation points are needed  the modules need to be configurable or split into more modules.

Comment: Thanks christopher. I tried by making the components shared in both the modules(editing module b in orca). It is working. Though I need to explore few more things like from which module the file will get deployed finally(when i tried it get deployed from module a rightly).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Dark](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/dark.htm) to decompile the merge modules and then either combine them to a single module or re-create merge module B without the conflicting file.